# Casting in c language

Tags: c, casting

I learn now about sockets and I find it very confusing because the casting structres.

The guide say to include 8 bit inside the sockaddr_in to compare it to sockaddr.

So my question is why to do it I mean when you cast you dont compare the char size to int

For example you do

```
char a[1]='1';
int b=(int)a;
```

and not

```
char a[2]='1';//compare to size of int
int b=(int)a;
```

so how is it working?

Is it diiferent when its castig strucres?
If yes so why?

Comment: `char a[2]='1'` will not compile nor will `char a[1]='1'`

Comment: Why it will not compile?

Comment: You can't cast `struct`s so I have no idea what this is about.

Comment: Berkeley was definitely into casig strucres.  An LSD side-effect.

Comment: `char a[2]="1"` will work. How can you assign a `char` value to a `char*`?

Comment: @HansPassant: I think the OP meant "castig", not "casing". That's quite a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing pointers to structures, the function that receives it may try to access any of all its fields.

If you receive a `struct something *`, you expect that you can read any of the `sizeof(struct something)` bytes following the pointer you receive. So, not reserving those bytes in your own `struct` would make them incompatible - whenever the function tries to access the bytes you haven't allocated, it would be accessing non-reserved memory, so it can be a segmentation fault, or can corrupt another's structure data.

---

Look at this program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) pair {
        short first;
        char second;
        long int third;
        int forth;
        char last;
};

void main(void) {
        struct pair myPair;
        printf("myPair         is at 0x%x\n", &myPair);
        printf("myPair.first   is at 0x%x\n", &(myPair.first));
        printf("myPair.second  is at 0x%x\n", &(myPair.second));
        printf("myPair.third   is at 0x%x\n", &(myPair.third));
        printf("myPair.forth   is at 0x%x\n", &(myPair.forth));
        printf("myPair.last    is at 0x%x\n", &(myPair.last));
}
```

And a sample output:

```
myPair         is at 0xabbd0aa0
myPair.first   is at 0xabbd0aa0
myPair.second  is at 0xabbd0aa2
myPair.third   is at 0xabbd0aa3
myPair.forth   is at 0xabbd0aab
myPair.last    is at 0xabbd0aaf
```

What we've learnt here is that each field is stored next to the previous one in memory, more precisely `sizeof(previous_field)` bytes to the right of the previous field (when `struct` is `packed` - see [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type-Attributes) for understanding why packed, but this is the ideal case).

So, imagine we would like to create another `struct` to be compatible with this one. If we create something like:

```
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) small_pair {
        long int first;
        char second;
        int third;
        char forth;
};
```

We can pass a `struct small_pair *` to any function that expects a `struct pair *` by casting:

```
void my_function(struct pair *);

void main(void) {
    struct small_pair my_small_pair;
    // ...
    my_function((struct pair*) &my_small_pair);
    // ...
}

void my_function(struct pair *a_pair) {
    //...
    printf("Second character of pair is %c\n", a_pair->second);
    //...
    printf("Last character of pair is %c\n", a_pair->last);
    //...
}
```

Once compiled, accessing `a_pair->second` is "read the one byte which is two bytes after the start of the struct" (`0xabbd0aa2 - 0xabbd0aa0 = 2`). So that would be the third byte of the field `first` of a `struct small_pair`, whichever value it has.

But, what about `a_pair->last`? It's `0xf` (15) bytes after the struct's start, but it's clearly out of it's space (`sizeof(struct small_pair)` is just 14).

So it will depend on the way variables got loaded in memory, but clearly we will not be referring to the value we wanted. The best case would be when that address is out of our process space, so we get a Segmentation Fault, and the program aborts. But it could well be that there's another variable declared in that position of memory, and we will be reading/writing a different variable from what we wanted, leaving to who-knows-what results.

So, if we just add another 2-bytes-long field to the end of the `struct small_pair`, we guarantee that every possible reference of a `struct pair` will still be correct in our own `struct`, so they'll be compatible at memory-level.

Then, it's still left the semantic-level compatibility, but that's a different story :)

Comment: So its not really casting beacuse its pointer?

Comment: @user1801625 I've just edited my answer, hope it helps clarifying this.

Comment: Can I copy this answer? I want to show it to some people

Comment: @user1801625 sure you can! Also, SO content is CC-BY-SA ;-) Glad it helps... (also helped for me, learnt a few things too)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the conventional C this is just not possible because C casts pointers not the data types. If you do this with a pointer, your program will place the byte of char as the most significant byte of int. Three following bytes will be filled with whatever follows your char variable. Please, never do this again!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the casts in Winsock is that they implement a weird broken form of polymorphism in which all structures are the same size (hence the unused array of bytes at the end of some structures) and functions take a "generic" structure (e.g. sockaddr).

So while with proper polymorphism you would have:

```
class SockAddr
{
    ...
};

class SockAddrIn : public SockAddr
{
    ...
};

class SockAddrIn6 : public SockAddr
{
    ...
};
```

With Winsock you have several unrelated structures that are all binary-compatible, and you have to cast them to the "generic" sockaddr when passing them to functions.